# Unable to create a new Socket in Android 4.1.2 and newer

Tags: android, sockets, freeze

In Android 2.3.3 (API lvl 10) the following code works but in Android 4.1.2 and beyond it hangs and will timeout when the socket is created.

```
int port = 2890;
InetAddress server_addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.1.1.3");
Socket s = new Socket(server_addr,port);
```

I have seen other posts about how this can be caused by IPv6 addresses and/or Sockets being used by the main thread but my code is only using IPv4 and is running inside a separate thread in a background service.  It also behaves the same inside an emulator or while being run on a real device.

Any thoughts/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit the stack trace into your post.

Answer (score 0):

On my project running on ICS 4.0+. It's work well

```
sk = new Socket(_ServerIP, PORT);
```

Comment: and _ServerIP would be, what?

Comment: _ServerIP = InetAddress.getByName(ServerIP);

where ServerIP is String represent ip address such as "192.168.1.1"